# Problems getting underline to fade in

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a blog for my friend and I can't seem to get the underline on the navlinks to fade in independent of the actual text, any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="navlinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="currentpage">Masthead</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navlinks a:hover {
border-bottom: 3px solid #CD2626;
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.navlinks a {
opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting a `border-bottom` on the non-hover rule, which is necessary for a CSS transition of this type. (This might not be strictly necessary (unsure), but at least that's the way I've seen it set up).

Furthermore, you are setting the transition function in the wrong place (shouldn't be in the `:hover` rule, probably just a style thing) and on the wrong property (that is, if you want the *underline* to fade in). Your full CSS for this should look like:

```
.navlinks a {
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;

    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.navlinks a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #CD2626;
}
```

If you also want the *opacity* to change (i.e. the entire text to fade in or out), re-add the `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` lines to their respective rules.